# Forwarded emails not creating a case record in Salesforce

Tags: apex, case, apex-email-service, email2case, inboundemail

We are using a custom object (TT_Case__c) to create records/cases whenever an email is received on our work email address. I have created an email service in Salesforce which uses the following apex class:

```
public class CaseEmailService implements Messaging.InboundEmailHandler {

    public Messaging.InboundEmailResult handleInboundEmail(Messaging.InboundEmail email, 
                                                           Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope) 
    {
        Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();   
        TT_Case__c ttCase = new TT_Case__c();

        // Check if the incoming email is a new email or reply/response to any previous email
        if(email.references == null){
            ttCase = createTTCase(email);
        } else {
            List<TT_Case__c> ttCaseList = getExistingRecord(email);
        }
        
        createTTEmailMessage(ttCase.Id, email);
            
        if(email.textAttachments != null){
            createTextAttachment(ttCase.Id, email);
        }
        
        if(email.binaryAttachments != null){
            createBinaryAttachment(ttCase.Id, email);
        }

          return result;
   }
    
    @testVisible  
    private static TT_Case__c createTTCase(Messaging.InboundEmail inboundMessage){

        TT_Case__c tt = new TT_Case__c();
        
        tt.TT_Email__c = inboundMessage.fromAddress;
        tt.TT_Name__c = inboundMessage.fromName;
        tt.Description__c = inboundMessage.htmlBody;
        tt.Opened__c = Datetime.now();
        tt.Subject__c = inboundMessage.subject;
        
                
        insert tt;
        return tt;
    }
    
    @testVisible
    private static void createTextAttachment(String parentRecordId, Messaging.InboundEmail emailMessage){
        List<Attachment> textAttachemntList = new List<Attachment>();
        for (Messaging.Inboundemail.TextAttachment tAttachment : emailMessage.textAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Name = tAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = Blob.valueOf(tAttachment.body);
            attachment.ParentId = parentRecordId;
            textAttachemntList.add(attachment);
          }
        if(textAttachemntList.size()>0){
            insert textAttachemntList;
        }
    }
    
    @testVisible
    private static void createBinaryAttachment(String parentRecordId, Messaging.InboundEmail emailMessage){
        List<Attachment> binaryAttachment = new List<Attachment>();
        for (Messaging.Inboundemail.BinaryAttachment bAttachment : emailMessage.binaryAttachments) {
            Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
            attachment.Name = bAttachment.fileName;
            attachment.Body = bAttachment.body;
            attachment.ParentId = parentRecordId;
            binaryAttachment.add(attachment);
        }
        
        if(binaryAttachment.size()>0){
            insert binaryAttachment;
        }
    }
   
     @testVisible
    private static void createTTEmailMessage(String ttCaseId, Messaging.InboundEmail email){
        EmailMessage em = new EmailMessage();

        em.Subject = email.Subject;
        em.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody;
        em.Incoming = true;
        em.Status = '1';
        em.ToAddress = (email.ToAddresses == null || email.ToAddresses.isEmpty()) ? '' : String.join(email.ToAddresses, ',');
        em.FromAddress = email.fromAddress;
        em.FromName = email.fromName;
        em.RelatedToId = ttCaseId;
        em.CcAddress = (email.ccAddresses == null || email.ccAddresses.isEmpty()) ? '' : String.join(email.ccAddresses, ',');

        insert em;

    }
    
    // Method to link the incoming email to an existing case record
    @testVisible
    private static List<TT_Case__c> getExistingRecord(Messaging.InboundEmail email){
        List<TT_Case__c> ttCase = new List<TT_Case__c>();
        List<String> referenceId = email.references;
        List<EmailMessage> prevmail = [SELECT RelatedToId from EmailMessage WHERE ThreadIdentifier =: referenceId];
        ttCase = [SELECT Id FROM TT_Case__c WHERE Id=: prevmail[0].RelatedToId];
        if(ttCase.isempty())
        {
            TT_Case__c ttCaseObj = createTTCase(email);
            ttCase.add(ttCaseObj);
        }
        return ttCase;
    } 

}
```

When a user send a new email to the address, it successfully creates a record/case. But the issue is it not working when a user forwards another email to the address. For example, a user wants to forward a different email to our work email address and this should creates a new case record but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

If i am not mistaken in a forward, the `email.reference` exists, thus you hit your else condition where it trys to find in your db the matching TT_Case__c. As it is not found, you create a new case, and add it to your `ttCaseList`.
you then call  `createTTEmailMessage(ttCase.Id, email);` but the ttCase.Id does not exist as it has not been assigned. You should have something like ttCaseList.get(0) to have it assigned.
you are thus probably assigning null on the line `em.RelatedToId = ttCaseId;` thus the mail is not linked to your case.

I highly suggest that you create a debug log on your user that handles your email service and then see what is the debug log that you get on this creation.

Finally small hint, the length of the html body is limited thus you may want to truncate it like `em.HtmlBody = email.htmlBody.length() > 32000  ? null: email.htmlBody;`

hope this helps a little bit